# CUDA/C - Using malloc in kernel functions gives strange results

Tags: cuda, malloc, gpgpu

I'm new to CUDA/C and new to stack overflow. This is my first question.

I'm trying to allocate memory dynamically in a kernel function, but the results are unexpected.
I read using malloc() in a kernel can lower performance a lot, but I need it anyway so I first tried with a simple `int **` array just to test the possibility, then I'll actually need to allocate more complex structs.

In my main I used `cudaMalloc()` to allocate the space for the array of `int *`, and then I used `malloc()` for every thread in the kernel function to allocate the array for every index of the outer array. I then used another thread to check the result, but it doesn't always work.

Here's main code:

```
#define N_CELLE 1024*2
#define L_CELLE 512

extern "C" {

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  int *result = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int));
  int *d_result;
  int size_numbers = N_CELLE * sizeof(int *);
  int **d_numbers;

  cudaMalloc((void **)&d_numbers, size_numbers);
  cudaMalloc((void **)&d_result, sizeof(int *));

  kernel_one<<<2, 1024>>>(d_numbers);
  cudaDeviceSynchronize();
  kernel_two<<<1, 1>>>(d_numbers, d_result);

  cudaMemcpy(result, d_result, sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

  printf("%d\n", *result);

  cudaFree(d_numbers);
  cudaFree(d_result);
  free(result);
}

}
```

I used `extern "C"`because I could't compile while importing my header, which is not used in this example code. I pasted it since I don't know if this may be relevant or not.

This is kernel_one code:

```
__global__ void kernel_one(int **d_numbers) {
  int i = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x;
  d_numbers[i] = (int *)malloc(L_CELLE*sizeof(int));
  for(int j=0; j<L_CELLE;j++)
    d_numbers[i][j] = 1;
}
```

And this is kernel_two code:

```
__global__ void kernel_two(int **d_numbers, int *d_result) {
  int temp = 0;
  for(int i=0; i<N_CELLE; i++) {
    for(int j=0; j<L_CELLE;j++)
      temp += d_numbers[i][j];     
  }
  *d_result = temp;
}
```

Everything works fine (aka the count is correct) until I use less than 1024*2*512 total blocks in device memory. For example, if I `#define N_CELLE 1024*4` the program starts giving "random" results, such as negative numbers.
Any idea of what the problem could be? 
Thanks anyone!

Comment: So you start learning C and you first test project is ... CUDA ! Nice pick ! By the way, you code in C++, because `extern "C"` don't exist... in C. That could explain your bug. `kernel_one<<<2, 1024>>>(d_numbers;` I sure this doesn't compile.

Comment: How is `N_CELLE` shared with kernel?...

Comment: N_CELLE is defined is the same .cu file of main and kernel functions.

And I fixed the pasting typo, thx.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In-kernel memory allocation draws memory from a statically allocated runtime heap. At larger sizes, you are exceeding the size of that heap and then your two kernels are attempting to read and write from uninitialised memory. This produces a runtime error on the device and renders the results invalid.  You would already know this if you either added correct API error checking on the host side, or ran your code with the  `cuda-memcheck` utility.

The solution is to ensure that the heap size is set to something appropriate before trying to run a kernel. Adding something like this:

```
 size_t heapsize = sizeof(int) * size_t(N_CELLE) * size_t(2*L_CELLE);
 cudaDeviceSetLimit(cudaLimitMallocHeapSize, heapsize);
```

to your host code before any other API calls, should solve the problem.

Comment: Thx @talonmies I made a fast try and it worked fine! I'll make other tests tomorrow.
I tried `cuda-memcheck` but it gives me `Internal error (7) - No CUDA-MEMCHECK results found` on every program I run it and I couldn't find a solution for it

Answer (score 0):

I don't know anything about CUDA but these are severe bugs:

- You cannot convert from `int**` to `void**`. They are not compatible types. Casting doesn't solve the problem, but hides it.
- `&d_numbers` gives the *address of a pointer to pointer* which is wrong. It is of type `int***`.

Both of the above bugs result in undefined behavior. If your program somehow seems to works in some condition, that's just by pure (bad) luck only.

Comment: I can be wrong, but that's the usage I saw of the cudaMalloc API

Comment: @Ratacand I very much doubt it told you to pass a `int***` to a function expecting a `void**`.

Comment: so what do you suggest to do?

Comment: Of course you can convert `int**` to `void**`. C11 6.3.2.3 point 7 says a pointer to an object type may be converted to a pointer to another object type and the operation is only undefined if the resulting pointer is not aligned. I think we can safely assume that a `void*` has the same alignment requirements as `int*` on any sane platform.

Comment: @Ratacand Get rid of the `&` to begin with?

Comment: that gives a segfault :/

Comment: @JeremyP Oh the actual conversion is ok, you just can't use the data pointed at in a meaningful way, because of strict aliasing violations, C11 6.5/7.

Comment: @Ratacand I mean: `int* d_numbers; ... cudaMalloc( (void**)&d_numbers, size_numbers);`. Though this is still fishy code - but might be guaranteed by some CUDA non-standard extension that I'm not aware of.

Comment: Thx @Shadow I'll give it a try